# SQL evaluates to true when it should not

Tags: sql

I have this SQL code

```
$passwordQuery = mysql_query("UPDATE `Medarbejder` SET `password` = '$password' WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$oldPassword'")or die(mysql_error());
            if($passwordQuery){
```

And no matter if $oldPassword is equal to `password` or not, it evaluates to true, which is rather annoying and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for the affected rows count you can use `mysql_affected_rows` in your PHP code.

[For Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 2):

I think `mysql_query` will return TRUE regardless of whether it updates a row or not. It only return FALSE on error as per the manual said

> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

I think what you want is checking the update count as well -- in addition to error checking

Comment: Oh okay.. derp, thanks :) will try it out just quick :)
Do you know of a way to check if it actually updates then?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but your update will not fail even if there is no record found, he will just update nothing! :-)

Comment: Okay thanks :) do you know of  way to actually check if it updates something then? :)

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) will return the number of affected rows after update.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
$passwordQuery = mysql_query("UPDATE `Medarbejder` SET `password` = '$password' WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$oldPassword'")or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_affected_rows()==0){
        //alternative to false return of query
        }
        else if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
        //alternative to true return of query
        }
```

Comment: `mysql_affected_rows()`

is used to return the number of rows changed due to the query processed recently in the current function or processing block.
If the password and/or username is not equal then this function would return 0 else any number greater than 0.